# Installing Java EE 6 SDK

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

This is the installation file:
[Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 6 SDK Update 3 (with JDK 6u27)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-6u27-downloads-458958.html)

The error occured during glassfish installation domain is:
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat --user admin --passwordfile - create-domain --savelogin --checkports=false --adminport 4848 --instanceport 8080 --domainproperties=jms.port=7676:domain.jmxPort=8686:orb.listener.port=3700:http.ssl.port=8181:orb.ssl.port=3820:orb.mutualauth.port=3920 domain1 Error: could not open `C:\glassfish3\jdk\jre\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Does C:\glassfish3\jdk\jre\lib\i386\jvm.cfg exists? which version of windows? Maybe you need to run this as the admin user.

Comment: Windows vista Ultimate 32 bit

Comment: C:\glassfish3\jdk\jre\lib\i386\jvm.cfg It doesn't exists. I don't know why, but the installer creates Java Runtime Environment in glassfish path and it doesn't complete the installation.
If you try to compare the real path of Java installation that is: C:\Program Files\Java\jreX\lib\i386\jvm.cfg the file exists, but not in glassfish.

Answer (score 1):

Start regedit, go to HKLM/Software/JavaSoft/Java Runtime Environment/ and find value
CurrentVersion. Then there should be some subkeys, one of them will be the one found in "CurrentVersion". Check the paths in there.

Now if any of the subsection match the reality, you can change the "CurrentVersion" to the name of that section. Otherwise you can try modifying the paths in the "CurrentVersion" section to the paths you would like to see there (maybe C:/j2sdk1.4.2_03/jre/...).

Comment: It's not really clear. The problem is in glassfish configuration not in Java, infact what the installer wants is this file lib\i386\jvm.cfg but it's located in C:\Program Files\Java\jreX\lib\i386\jvm.cfg where i have installed before the Java(TM) 7 Update 1