# Error when starting Glassfish Server from Eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I'm using Windows Vista Ultimate 32 bit, and I've installed GlassFish 3.1.1 outside of Eclipse.

When I start Glassfish Server, a window (Problem Occurred) shows the following error message:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Publishing to GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3 (Java EE 6) at localhost...".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Impossible to say from the information given (which should be obvious). Is there anything in the server log?

Comment: I know, you are right, but the server log is empty beacuse the window is shown 1 millisecond after i click the button Start. Before do this i have had a problem with glassfish installation/configuration, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941028/installing-java-ee-6-sdk      
To overcome the problem i downloaded the zip file installation and starting Eclipse

Answer (score 4):

For passer by :

Check `Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments > YourGlassfish > Edit`. Verify the correct JDK is installed. You may get a NPE though, see [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS-375)